# how to handle unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float' in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe looks like this

```
   df A                df b
|  gmv   |          |  gmv  |
| 500.00 |          |  NaN  |
| 190.00 |          |  NaN  |
| 624.00 |          | 10.00 |
```

this code `a['gmv'].fillna(0) + b['gmv'].fillna(0)`

return error `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'`

I want result looks like this

```
    df              
|  gmv   |         
| 500.00 |         
| 190.00 |          
| 634.00 |
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If want output `Series` in floats convert first column by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
c = a['gmv'].fillna(0).astype(float) + b['gmv'].fillna(0)
print (c)
0    500.0
1    190.0
2    634.0
Name: gmv, dtype: float64
```

If want output `Series` in Decimal convert second DataFrame:

```
from decimal import Decimal

c = a['gmv'].fillna(0) + b['gmv'].fillna(0).apply(Decimal)
print (c)
0    500
1    190
2    634
Name: gmv, dtype: object

print (type(c.iat[0]))
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```